# Two results to one mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've successfully managed to output the posts of a users friends...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_posts` WHERE user_id IN ($friend) ORDER BY `time` DESC");
```

This outputs all of the friends posts of the user. However I want to get the posts of the user itself AS WELL as the friends posts...this is what I have tried...

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_posts` WHERE user_id IN ($friend) AND `user_id`=$session_user_id ORDER BY `time` DESC");
```

I even tried making another mysql statement just to load the users posts however when I did that, the users posts were being outputted first in the order of the time that they were outputted and then after the users posts were the friends posts shown...
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually want an `OR` condition:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_posts` WHERE user_id IN ($friend) OR `user_id`=$session_user_id ORDER BY `time` DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_posts` WHERE user_id IN ($friend) OR `user_id`=$session_user_id ORDER BY `time` DESC");
```

That will return anything where user_id is in your array; as well as the user's own ID.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly chwhat you are trying to do all you need do is change 
And 'user_id = $session_iser_id
To 
Or 'user_id = $session_iser_id